# Allow floating DIVs to overlap when window is smaller

Tags: css, css-float

I'm trying to take a row of left-floating DIVs and make them overlap if the width of the container DIV is smaller than the width of all the DIVs.

This is what I'm working with:

http://shifuimam.com/moop/w/skins/moop/test.php

Right now, if the window resizes, the DIVs move down to the next line. I can change the **overflow** property, but that will make the container DIV scroll. What I want is for the DIVs to overlap each other to constrain to the width of the window, regardless of size.

Is this even possible? I tried with **min-width** and **max-width**, but that didn't work.

Comment: I think for that you need javascript/jquery: I'd monitor the width of the window and then use absolute positioning and z-index to get the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

Use percentage for .toontab class you're using. Yet you have to use media query for long range support

```
.toontab {
  position: relative;
  width: 8%;
  height: 3.5em;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1.5em;
  font-size: 11pt;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Well, the number of tabs will vary - not sure if that matters. Also: the tabs are still going to the next line if the width of the window is too small.